# Access JSON data returned by SendGrid

Tags: php, json, sendgrid

I am working with the SendGrid PHP Library (https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/php.html).

The response is sent ass JSON - e.g. should be something like:

```
{"message":"success"}
```

I can send a simple email via:

```
<?php
$root="../../";
require $root . 'vendor/autoload.php';

$sendgrid = new SendGrid($SendGrid);
$email = new SendGrid\Email();
$email
    //->addTo('you@me.com')
    ->addTo('you@me.com')
    ->setFrom('me@bar.com')
    ->setSubject('Subject goes here')
    ->setText('Hello World!')
    ->setHtml('<strong>Hello World!</strong>')
;

$res = $sendgrid->send($email);
?>
```

When I display the output of $res e.g. using PHP-REF (https://github.com/digitalnature/php-ref) I can see that it looks like this:

[image: PHP-REF view of $res returned by SendGrid]

It appears the response is an Object - presumably JSON?

However, I can't access the data as JSON because if I try this:

```
$newtxt = json_decode($res);
```

I get this error:

> Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\jim\001-jimpix\contact_old\test-send-grid.php on line 24

And if I try this:

```
$j_array = json_decode($res, true);
```

I get the same error.

I can hard code the "$res" value as:

```
$res = "{\"message\":\"success\"}";
```

And then that works.

However, I can't work out how to access the JSON returned by SendGrid.

I've tried various things like:

```
$res = json_decode(json_encode($res),TRUE);
```

Presumably there is a way to access the JSON returned by SendGrid so I can access the JSON data.

But I don't know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the PHP-REF response, `$res` is not the raw JSON.

You can access the result simply by using `$res->getBody()`. This will give you the parsed JSON from SendGrid.

You **do not** need to `json_decode` this.